# PHP ob_start not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to PHP and Code Ignitor, Facing some issue while trying to convert dynamic data content into static html file. This is code snippet. when i request code snippet file it prints only Error 111111111 nothing else. not able to understand what is the error here.

This is my original Code and here am trying to generate static html file with dynamic content. It doesn't works for me

```
<?php
    echo "Error 111111111";
    ob_start();
    $fileName = "sample.html";
?>
<html>
<body>
    Some html is here       
</body>
</html>
<?php
    try{ 
           $output = ob_get_contents(); // get contents of trapped output

            //write to file, e.g.
           $newfile = $fileName; 
           $file = fopen ($newfile, "w"); 
           fwrite($file, $output); 
           fclose ($file);  
           ob_end_clean(); // discard trapped output and stop trapping
    }catch (Exception $ex){                
      echo "Error ".$ex->getMessage();
    }      

?>
```

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see an error?

`ob_start()` suppresses all output until `ob_flush()` is called. You're not calling `ob_flush()`, so nothing after the `ob_start()` will be output. That's what you're seeing, and that's exactly the way it's supposed to work.

I suppose the real question is what were you trying to achieve?

The code snippet is quite confusing, because `ob_start()` doesn't generate any exceptions, yet you've put it into a `try` / `catch` block. Your `catch` section will never be called because nothing in the `try` block will ever generate any exceptions.

So what were you trying to do here? The answer to that may help us give you more guidance.

Comment: if there is no such error then why it not prints  echo "Error 22222";

Comment: @Yashwant Chavan - okay you've completely changed the code now, and the '22222' only applies to the first version of the question. But based on the original question, the '22222' does print, but because ob_start has been called, it gets stored in the output buffer rather than being given to the browser. If you call ob_flush, it will be sent to the browser. However, your updated code is completely different: it does make it easier to see what you are actually trying to do, but I'd need to write a whole new answer to try to help you understand it.

Answer (score 1):

ob_start marks where buffered output should begin, but AFAIK you also have to tell PHP to end buffering and output the current contents: [ob_end_flush()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php)